# wont let me pull my list on my cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Given a

`cshtml` partial within another `cshtml`

```
@model List<Participant>;
@{
if(Model != null)
    {
        foreach(Participant i in Model)
            {
                <p>@i.ParticipantFirstName</p>
            }
    }
    if(Model == null)
    {
        <p>placeholder:: the list is empty</p>
    }
}
<p>test</p>
```

and a controller,

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("dashboard")]
    public IActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        if(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId") == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
        ViewBag.loggedinUser = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("DashboardTab", 0);
        List<Participant> allParticipants = db.Participants.Include(i=>i.Parent).ToList();
        return View("Dashboard", allParticipants);
    }
```

and this model,

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LeagueProject.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
       private Context db;
        public ViewModel(Context context)
        {
            db = context;
        }
        public Participant participant { get; set; }

        public class Participant
        {
        [Key]
        public int ParticipantId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "must be at least 2 characters")]
        public string ParticipantFirstName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
        [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "must be at least 2 characters")]
        public string ParticipantLastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
        public string ParticipantGender { get; set; }

        // [Required(ErrorMessage = "is required")]
        // [Range(8, 20, ErrorMessage="this league if roages 8-19")]
        // public int ParticipantAge { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Need a date of birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public System.DateTime ParticipantDOB { get; set; }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User Parent { get; set; }

        public List<MMLeagueParticipant> allLeagues { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

I get the exception

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LeagueProject.Models.Participant]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'LeagueProject.Models.ViewModel'.

I can't figure out why I'm getting the error. I'm new to the framework. This worked on a previous project on something similar.

Comment: i also tryied adding this on my main cshtml where i call the tab that contains the partial:::: <partial name="_YourKidsTab" model="@Model.allParticipants">

Comment: Can you show the line that includes the partial in the other cahtml

Answer (score 0):

It should be `List<Participant>` in the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    //...

    public List<Participant> participants { get; set; }

}
```

Then in your controller , return this ViewModel to the main view.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("dashboard")]
public IActionResult Dashboard()
{
    if(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId") == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
    ViewBag.loggedinUser = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId");
    HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("DashboardTab", 0);
    List<Participant> allParticipants = db.Participants.Include(i=>i.Parent).ToList();
    var viewmodel = new ViewModel();
    viewmodel.participants = allParticipants;
    return View("Dashboard", viewmodel);
}
```